# addEventListener works on static buttons, but not on dynamically generated buttons

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I have a button in popup.html, like so.

```
<button id='test'>TEST BUTTON</button>
```

Then I have this function and listener in a separate js file.

```
function getAjax()
{
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {code:"alert('works!')"});
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    var buttons = document.querySelectorAll('button');
    for (var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
    buttons[i].addEventListener('click', getAjax);
  }
});`
```

The function gets called when I use the button above. Now if I generate buttons dynamically, like so:

```
var AJAXholder = document.getElementById("AJAXholder"); 
var button = document.createElement("button");
button.setAttribute("class", "app-buttons");                
button.setAttribute("id", ""+ objects[i].name +"");
button.setAttribute("name", ""+ objects[i].name +"");
    var buttonText = document.createTextNode(""+ objects[i].name +"");
    button.appendChild(buttonText);
AJAXholder.appendChild(button);
```

These buttons are created correctly, but are not able to fire that same function. Is there anything I can do to make it work?

EDIT:

I added a new event listener as I make a new button, like so:

```
var newlistener = document.getElementById(""+ objects[i].name +"").addEventListener('click', getAjax);
```

It seems to work. Wouldn't mind learning a better way anyway, or I'll vote to delete when I'm allowed.

Answer (score 1):

Is your button-generating code contained in your `DOMContentLoaded` listener function? If not, my guess is that `DOMContentLoaded` is firing before the JS script runs to create the buttons, so `querySelectorAll('button')` gets an empty list, since no buttons exist yet.  Make sure your button-creation script runs chronologically after (or, better still, within) your `DOMContentLoaded` listener function.